# Python 3: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'choice'

Tags: python, random

Trying to run this python 3 program but it seems it can't run past the first loop.

```
import webbrowser
import time
import random

while True:
    sites = ['www.google.com', 'www.mastercode.com', 'www.youtube.com']
    site = random.choice(sites)
    visit = ("http://{}".format(site))
    webbrowser.open(vist)
    time.sleep(2)
```

After the 1st loop it gives this error:

**AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'choice'**

I am unable to fix it.I am still new to python 3.

Comment: Looks like you are using a variable named `random` and somewhere it is pointed to a `int` object.

Comment: You also missing a single quote `'` before `www.youtube.com`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM what do you suggest i do

Comment: Once I replaced `vist` with `visit` here `open(vist)` it just works for me.

Comment: @MaorRefaeli i noticed that earlier.I corrected it but the program still have issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must have a variable called `random`, I mean you had override the default random module of python, change that variable name from random to something else.

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar.Your solution gives another error 'random not defined'

Comment: So do not delete random, just change that variable that named random.